# rolling join two data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

`dt1` has `val` of interest in the correct sequence

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.frame(id = 1,
                  key = c(paste0("a_",1:6),paste0("b_",1:6)), 
                  val = c(122,128,134, rep(NA,3),c(110,112,114),rep(NA,3)),
                  var = c(rep("a",6),rep("b",6)))

   id key val var
1   1 a_1 122   a
2   1 a_2 128   a
3   1 a_3 134   a
4   1 a_4  NA   a
5   1 a_5  NA   a
6   1 a_6  NA   a
7   1 b_1 110   b
8   1 b_2 112   b
9   1 b_3 114   b
10  1 b_4  NA   b
11  1 b_5  NA   b
12  1 b_6  NA   b
```

`dt2` also has the `val` of interest in the correct sequence but also some extra `val`

```
dt2 <- data.frame(id = 1,
                  key = c(paste0("a_",c(1,3:6)),paste0("b_",c(2,4:6))),
                  val = c(122,127,122,128,134,110,110,112,114),
                  var = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",4)))

  id key val var
1  1 a_1 122   a
2  1 a_3 127   a
3  1 a_4 122   a
4  1 a_5 128   a
5  1 a_6 134   a
6  1 b_2 110   b
7  1 b_4 110   b
8  1 b_5 112   b
9  1 b_6 114   b
```

I want to match the sequence of values from `dt2` to the sequence of values in `dt1` and ignore extra values that are in `dt2`.
I have tried a rolling join backwards as values of interest in `dt2` are culstered towards the end of the sequence.

## Current attempt:

```
setDT(dt1,key = c("id","var","val"))
setDT(dt2,key = c("id","var","val"))
dt1[dt2, roll = -Inf]
   id key val var i.key
1:  1 a_1 122   a   a_1 # wrong
2:  1 a_1 122   a   a_4 
3:  1 a_2 127   a   a_3 # wrong
4:  1 a_2 128   a   a_5 
5:  1 a_3 134   a   a_6 
6:  1 b_1 110   b   b_2 # wrong
7:  1 b_1 110   b   b_4 
8:  1 b_2 112   b   b_5
9:  1 b_3 114   b   b_6
```

It looks like duplicate values from `dt2` that are in `dt1` but *not* in the sequence I am looking for are causing an issue. Also I want to keep `i.key` to know the original key as it will be used for other processing. I have also tried: `merge(dt1,dt2)`

## Desired output:

```
id key val var i.key
 1 a_1 122  a  a_4
 1 a_2 128  a  a_5
 1 a_3 134  a  a_6
 1 b_1 110  b  b_4
 1 b_2 112  b  b_5
 1 b_3 114  b  b_6
```

I would be grateful for some guidance

Comment: is the sequence in consecutive positions? for e.g. do you consider c(122,128,134) from `dt1` to match with c(122, 345, 128, 678, 134) ?

Comment: The sequence in `dt1` is consecutive so effectively trying to match `c(122,128,134)` as a sequence and not value by value in `dt2`by `id` and `var` thanks

Comment: are sequences of any particular length of in dt1? Are they surrounded by NAs? sorry for the multiple qns as this is a very interesting qn

Comment: Seems like this problem is related to Multiple Sequence Alignment:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497747/how-to-perform-basic-multiple-sequence-alignments-in-r

Comment: No problem, sequences in dt1 are 2:6 values in length,then NA will always fill to 6, after the seqence never before. Therefore, in dt1
2 values will always be followed by 4NA,3 values followed by 3NA etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that first joins back onto `dt2` to filter out `key == key` pairs because you can't do a non-equi join and rolling join at the same time in `data.table`.

Also remember that only the *last* column in your `on =` argument can be rolling, so I recommend always explicitly defining it.

```
library(data.table)
dt2[dt1, on = .(id,var,val),nomatch = 0][
  key != i.key][dt1,on = .(id,var,val,i.key=key), roll = -Inf, nomatch = 0][
    ,.SD[.N],by = .(id,val,var)][,.(id,val,var,key1 = i.key,key2 = key)]
   id val var key1 key2
1:  1 122   a  a_1  a_4
2:  1 128   a  a_2  a_5
3:  1 134   a  a_3  a_6
4:  1 110   b  b_1  b_4
5:  1 112   b  b_2  b_5
6:  1 114   b  b_3  b_6
```

Comment: @jangorecki based on your tag history, you love `data.table` even more than me. I wish there was a less messy way to do multi-line `data.table` code.

Comment: `mergelist` is coming to ease some join use cases, but unfortunatelly not non-equi joins (yet): https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4370

Comment: This looks promising. Looking forward to having it in the CRAN version.

Comment: Thanks, was really struggling to get anywhere with this

Comment: @chinsoon12, the column `key` is class `character` and it works OK. From `help("data.table")`: "roll: Applies to the last join column, generally a date but can be **any ordered variable**, irregular and including gaps."

Comment: @IanCampbell, thanks! it was my fault. i was using `setDT` without the `key=`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that we need to find the whole sequence from `dt1` within `dt2`, here is another option:

```
setDT(dt1)
setDT(dt2)
cols <- c("sid", "cnt")

#create sequence index and count of non-NAs
DT1 <- dt1[!is.na(val)][, (cols) := .(seq(.N), .N), .(id, var)]

#inner join to id, var, val that exists in both
DT2 <- DT1[dt2, on=.(id, var, val), nomatch=0L, .(id, var, val, sid, cnt, i.key)]

#identify rows with consecutive seq index and filter for those rows
consec <- DT2[, if(.N == cnt[1L]) .SD, .(cs=cumsum(c(0L, diff(sid)!=1L)))]

#perform join to get desired output
DT1[consec, on=.(id, var, val)][, c(cols, "cs", "i.cnt") := NULL][]
```

output:

```
   id key val var i.key
1:  1 a_1 122   a   A_4
2:  1 a_2 128   a   A_5
3:  1 a_3 134   a   A_6
4:  1 b_1 110   b   B_4
5:  1 b_2 112   b   B_5
6:  1 b_3 114   b   B_6
7:  1 c_1 110   c   C_3
8:  1 c_2 112   c   C_5
9:  1 c_3 114   c   C_6
```

data with additional group based on comment:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.frame(id = 1,
  key = c(paste0("a_",1:6),paste0("b_",1:6),paste0("c_",1:6)),
  val = c(122,128,134, rep(NA,3),c(110,112,114),rep(NA,3), c(110,112,114),rep(NA,3)),
  var = c(rep("a",6),rep("b",6),rep("c",6)))
dt2 <- data.frame(id = 1,
  key = c(paste0("A_",c(1,3:6)),paste0("B_",c(2,4:6)),paste0("C_",c(2,3:6))),
  val = c(122,127,122,128,134,110,110,112,114,134,110,200,112,114),
  var = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",4),rep("c",5)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have also said that in dt2 there can be an incorrect value between the correct sequence that dt1 has. For example if we change the last values in dt2 to ..134,110,200,112,114) is there a condition to pass the 200 and still look for 110,112,114?

Comment: @e.matt i added more data based on your comment and updated the code to address that. But I am assuming that this incorrect value does not exists in dt1

Answer (score 0):

There is probably nicer way to do it, but I think this will work:

```
merge(dt1, dt2, by = c( "val","var")) %>%
  arrange(key.x) %>%
  filter(key.x != key.y) %>%
  mutate (id = id.x, key = key.x, i.key = key.y) %>%
  select (id, key, val, var, i.key)
```

Result:

```
  id key val var i.key
1  1 a_1 122   a   a_4
2  1 a_2 128   a   a_5
3  1 a_3 134   a   a_6
4  1 b_1 110   b   b_2
5  1 b_1 110   b   b_4
6  1 b_2 112   b   b_5
7  1 b_3 114   b   b_6
```

Comment: It seems like the OP only wants one roll per `(id,val,var)`. You could add a `group_by(id,key,val) %>% filter(row_number() == n())`

Comment: Yep, see it now. Good catch.

Comment: Thanks for another approach!